# React Native Error : [Unhandled promise rejection : FirebaseError: Expected type 'Da', but it was: a custom Ua object]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am using react native to make tinder clone.

The above error is shown when a user right swipes a card.

I am using Firebase to store data.

This the code where the problem is but can't one, Please help.

Code:

```
// check if the user swiped on you...
    getDoc(doc(db, "users", userSwiped.id, "matches", user.uid)).then(
      (documentSnapshot) => {
        console.log(documentSnapshot);
        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
          // user has matched with you before you had matched with them.
          // Create a MATCH
          console.log(`hooray you MATCHED with ${userSwiped.displayName}`);
          setDoc(
            doc(db, "users", user.uid, "matches", userSwiped.id),
            userSwiped
          );

          // storing matched users data separately
          setDoc(doc(db, "matched", generateId(user.uid, userSwiped.id)), {
            user: {
              [user.uid]: loggedInUserProfile,
              [userSwiped.id]: userSwiped
            },
            usersMatched: [user.uid, userSwiped.id],
            timestamp: serverTimestamp()
          });

          navigation.navigate("Match", {
            loggedInUserProfile,
            userSwiped
          });
        }
        else {
          // user has swiped as first interaction between two or did not get swiped.
          console.log(`you swiped on ${userSwiped.displayName}`);
          setDoc(
            doc(db, "users", user.uid, "matches", userSwiped.id),
            userSwiped
          );
        }
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

check the code above

```
const loggedInProfile = await (
      await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid))
    ).data();
```

This code snippet worked for me.
and check if you're using getDoc's' instead of getDoc

I hope you'll find this helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).